# Python - find maxima based on conditions

Tags: python

I have a table with records which looks like this:

```
buyer=[name,value]
```

It is possible for any`id` to have several records in the table:

```
Name    Value
E        10
A        2
D        4
E        10
A        5
B        3
B        10
D        10
C        4
```

I am trying to filter this table based on the following logic: Select all records for those names for which the maximum value is not larger than 5. Based on the above example, I would select all records for names A and C, because their maxima are 5 and 3 respectively:

```
Name    Value
A        2
A        5
C        4
```

B, D and E will be excluded, because their maxima are 10 (for each of them).

How can I do this ?

Comment: what is your *a table with records* - a csv file? a dataframe?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest the data is an Excel file, but I know how to load it in Python. It is generated via Python anyway, now I just want to do some extra processing with ti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply with `pandas` module:

Let's say your data is in `test.csv` file.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", delim_whitespace=True)
idx = df.groupby('Name')['Value'].transform(max) <= 5

print(df[idx])
```

The output:

```
  Name  Value
1    A      2
4    A      5
8    C      4
```

---

[*pandas.DataFrame.groupby*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html?highlight=groupby#pandas.DataFrame.groupby)